# Share images using GwibberGtk

Tags: application-development, development

I am trying to implement social support into my app using Gwibber. What I need to do is share opened images but it seems that there are no ways to do that using libgwibber only. So are there any workaround to implement this feature?

I've tried to take a look in various API for web image hoster but all of them needs a registered user to upload files. Maybe it can be done using Ubuntu One / CouchDB APIs in Python by publicating an hosted image and then getting the public link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've found out already, the Gwibber API deals only with posting content to social networks.

If you want to host media such as pictures, on an external service, you'll need to find a public hosting service that has an API, get the public URL for the media item and pass it to Gwibber.

There are multiple services that you can use. I would recommend using Ubuntu One, but you can also probably use imgur.com or something else.